# How can I find the names of missing parameters in Python?

Tags: python, function, parameters

Whenever a Python function is called with missing named arguments, it produces a runtime error that lists the number of missing arguments:

`TypeError: getVolume() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

However, this doesn't tell me which specific arguments are missing. This runtime error message would be much more informative if it actually printed the names of the missing arguments, instead of just printing the number of arguments that are missing. This is especially important when working with functions that accept a large number of arguments: it's not always easy to remember the name of every single argument that is missing.

In general, is it possible to modify Python functions so that they will print the names of the missing arguments whenever arguments are missing?

```
def getVolume(length, width, height):
    return length*width*height;

print(getVolume(height=3, width=3));
```

Comment: Yes... but it's not trivial.

Comment: This has changed in Python3, you get the missing argument names for free.

Comment: @doukremt I get the same error in Python 3, which doesn't list the missing named arguments: `TypeError: getVolume() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`. What do you mean by this?

Comment: In Python3.3, I get this message: `missing 1 required positional argument: 'length'`.

Comment: @doukremt Can you post this as an answer so that my question won't be [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has changed in Python3.3 (at most), you get the missing argument names for free:

```
>>> def getVolume(length, width, height):
...     return length*width*height;
... 
>>> print(getVolume(height=3, width=3));
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getVolume() missing 1 required positional argument: 'length'
```

Comment: But how do you get the programatically?